# iOS10.0 AvPlayerItem.duration.value is not correct

Tags: ios, swift, avplayeritem

```
let value = avPlayerItem.currentItem.duration.value
print(value)
```

The result is:

iOS10.0 --->  29206080

iOS12.0 --->  48676608

Does anybody know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be your player item not in ready to play state. The recommended way of doing this, as described in the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/duration) is by observing the player item status:

```
[self.avPlayer.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
```

Then, inside observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // TODO: use either keyPath or context to differentiate between value changes
    if (self.avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration);
        // ...
    }
}
```